# copying file between folders using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, slurm

I am trying to submit several jobs in a consecutive manner.

Each job is located in a separate folder and each time that a job wants to be submitted, I need to copy some files from the previous folder into the new folder.

I wrote the below SLURM script, but it fails into copying files between folders.

Can someone please let me know what is the problem with my bash script?

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
#SBATCH --time=120:00:00
#SBATCH --partition=...
#SBATCH --ntasks=...
#SBATCH --job-name ...
#SBATCH --nodes=...
#SBATCH --gpus-per-node=...
#SBATCH --cpus-per-gpu=...
#SBATCH --account=...
#SBATCH --qos=...
#SBATCH --output=slurm-out
#SBATCH --error=slurm_error
 
 
cd $SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR
module load gcc/9.3.0
for((i=0;i<=4;i++))
  do
      cd $i
      if [$i -gt 0]
      then
          j=$(($i - 1))
          cp $j/file1  ./file2 

      fi
    csh README > log
    cd ../
done
```

I tried to use the bash script, but it failed into copying files between folders.

Comment: Try pasting the script into [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net/) and fixing its recommendations, you have some syntax errors and other semantic issues that might break your script.

Comment: Also be careful when using `cd` in a loop, if you're changing to relative directories you need to make sure you get back to your starting point before the next loop iteration otherwise `cd` will start to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Because **$j** is not an absolute path, you need to modify your script to handle what @tjm3772 pointed out.  Namely, change

```
cp $j/file1  ./file2
```

to

```
cp ../$j/file1  ./file2
```

Also, if you don't care if the file is modified from step to step, you might even consider using

```
ln ../$j/file1 ./file2
```

making your process both faster and using less disk space.